# Printing a value in dictionary that is of type list

Tags: python

I want to make a dictionary such that the value of first index is a list of string as the following:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.adjs = {}

    def printing(self):
       adjs = {1:['John', 'Mike', 'Alli'], 2:['Alice'], 3:['Bob']}
       for i in adjs[0]:
          print i, adjs[0][i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = Test()
    obj.printing()
```

If I want to only print the list stored in **of the first index**, i.e. `adjs[0]`, I don't get a result!! I believe Python's dictionary allows you to have such a dictionary as I did where the values can be a list of strings. Am I right?

Comment: There is no "first" index in a `dict`, since a `dict` doesn't store its keys in any guaranteed order. `adjs[0]` doesn't exist because you never added `0` as a key.

Comment: For the functionality you want, a different data structure might help you. A dict wasn't designed to work in this way.

Comment: Use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: to iterate through a dictionary use : `for k,v in dict.iteritems(): ...`

Answer (score -1):

Correct adjs[0], [key of dict] should be [1]
add len for know lenght of you dict and range for iter.
because you stay call array of list adjs[1][NUMBER INT OF LIST]

for you example:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.adjs = {}

    def printing(self):
       adjs = {1:['John', 'Mike', 'Alli'], 2:['Alice'], 3:['Bob']}
       for i in range(len(adjs[1])): # Change by 1, because you key is 1:....
          print i, adjs[1][i]

a = Test()
a.printing()
>>>0 John
>>>1 Mike
>>>2 Alli
```

or

```
dictt = {1: [99,44,77], 2:[33,66,66]}
mylist= [value for key, value in dictt.iteritems()]
print mylist
>>>[[99, 44, 77], [33, 66, 66]]
print mylist[0]
>>>[[99, 44, 77]]
print mylist[0][0]
>>>99
```